# Can someone explain the following Javascript code in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
               .data(data)
               .enter().append("g")
               .attr("transform", function(d, i) 
               { 
                 return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; 
               });
```

Can someone explain that why we should put the "+" before and after `i * barHeight`?

Comment: That's ordinary string concatenation.  What don't you understand?

Comment: thanks, i know for example, translate(10, 10) means translate the coordinates from the original position by 10 units in X and 10 units in Y. And I also know "+" here means string concatenation. but could you explain in details what components are concatenated in this line? if in the form "a + i * barHeight + b" here, what is a and b respectively?

Comment: @VividD Why did you edit the D3 tag back in? I removed it with revision 7 as this is not about D3 at all. A tag should indicate what the question is really about. This one is an absolute JS basic about string concatenation, operators and operands which could appear in many contexts other than D3. Even removing anything around the line containing the return would not change the meaning of the question.

Comment: @altocumulus The question is, in my understanding, about the whole code segment, which is in turn a pure D3 idiom.

Answer (score 1):

this will set the transform attribute of each element of the "g" collection according to the index of element.

eg: if barHeight = 10

```
<g tranform="tranlate(0, 0)"/>
<g tranform="tranlate(0, 10)"/>
<g tranform="tranlate(0, 20)"/>
<g tranform="tranlate(0, 30)"/>
<g tranform="tranlate(0, 40)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps to format the code.

```
var bar = chart.selectAll("g") 
.data(data) 
.enter().append("g") 
.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });
```

The answer has nothing to do with d3.  It's just how you make strings with variables in javascript.  Equivalent to something like this:

```
var name = "Johnny"
console.log("Hello " + name + " how are you today?")
//Hello Johnny how are you today?
```